# My function doesn't do anything with arrays

Tags: c, for-loop

Function could replace first n elements from array A with last n elements of array B.

Output is

> Array A
>
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
>
> Array B
>
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10

I tried to put `printf (i)` in every loop and it seems to be work fine but it do nothing with arrays a and b :(

```
void reparray(int *a, int *b, int n){
    int i;
    int last_element;
    int help[5] = {};

    i = 0;
    for (i; i<n; i++){
      help[i] = a[i];
    }

    last_element = 4;
    for (last_element; last_element>=n; last_element--){
        help[last_element] = b[last_element];
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i; i<n; i++){
        a[i] = help[i];
    }

    last_element = 4;
    for (last_element;last_element >= n; last_element--){
        b[last_element] = help[last_element];
    }


}


int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[5] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int n,i;

    reparray(a, b, 2);

   printf("Array A\n");

    i = 0;
    for (i; i<5; i++){
       printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    printf("Array B\n");

    i = 0;
    for (i; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: <O/T> you have several statements with no effect, for example `for (i;`, the `i;` does nothing. You can initialize the value in the loop, or initialize outside the loop as you have and do `for( ; i<5` ...`n` is also unused in `main`.

Comment: Have you tried running the program very carefully with pencil and paper?

Comment: so what's the expected output for `n == 2`? `a == {9, 10, 3, 4, 5}` and `b == {1, 2, 8, 9, 10}`?

Comment: @yano yes, exactly

Comment: In the last 2 `for` loops just swap `a` <=> `b`

Comment: @morep219 are you sure thats the expected? since your first sentence make me think that b should be `{6, 7, 8, 1, 2}`. Can you edit the question and add the exact expected output for a given n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your 2 last loops in `void reparray` do nothing except copying exact things which were already  in a and b

```
void reparray(int* a, int* b, int n) {
    int i;
    int last_element;
    int help[5] = {};

    i = 0;
    for (i; i < n; i++) {
        help[i] = a[i];
    }

    last_element = 4;
    for (last_element; last_element >= n; last_element--) {
        help[last_element] = b[last_element];
    }
    last_element = 4-1;
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = help[last_element];
        last_element++;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i; i< n; i++) {
        b[i] = help[i];
    }


}
```

for other input change `void reparray`

```
void reparray(int* a, int* b, int n) {
    int i;
    int last_element;
    int help[5] = {};

    i = 0;
    for (i; i < n; i++) {
        help[i] = a[i];
    }

    last_element = 4;
    for (last_element; last_element >= n; last_element--) {
        help[last_element] = b[last_element];
    }
    last_element = 4 - 1;
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = help[last_element];
        last_element++;
    }
    last_element = 4;
    int first_element = 0;
    for (i = last_element - n + 1; i < last_element + 1; i++) {
        b[i] = help[first_element];
        first_element++;
    }


}
```

Comment: How can I make output like `int A[] = {9, 10, 3, 4, 5};

int B[] = {6, 7, 8, 1, 2};` If n==2

Comment: @morep219 change last loop in `void reparray`  like that.